# How to route microphone & speaker audio between virtual machines?

Tags: audio, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create an interactive voice-tree for an art project. Think of something like a choose-you-own-adventure, but on the phone and with voice commands. I already have a fair amount of experience working with [Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/construct2) (game-making software), and can easily build a branching, voice controlled interaction loadable through a modern browser with it. For reasons relevant to the overall story, I need players to connect to the interaction through a Google Voice number they will call.

I already have a GV number and have written an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to auto-answer the Hangouts call, but I'm stuck trying to route the audio from the caller in Hangouts to the browser AND the audio response output of the browser back to the caller.

I know of an extremely primitive way to accomplish this, [which I've illustrated with this diagram:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is rather cumbersome and I suspect I can achieve my goal through virtualization or at the VERY least some sort of attenuation cables between two physical machines (I tried running a generic AUX cable between two laptops, but couldn't get speaker audio to go into microphone audio from one to the other).

I've been experimenting on [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) running Windows 8.1 with [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm)(no luck), [JACK](http://www.jackaudio.org/)(too robust), [Chevolume](http://www.chevolume.com/)(too limited), and [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/)(too limited).

I suspect VAC would be the best bet, but I can't seem to find a way to route Firefox audio output to a microphone input which directs to Chrome and vice versa. If I try accomplishing it all through just one virtual machine I have to use two different browsers for the voice-tree webpage and Hangouts call since Hangouts pushes its audio through Chrome (even the stand-alone application).

Is there any way to route microphone input and speaker output separately between two virtual machines? If not, could I still try and accomplish this with a specific type of cables between two laptops running windows 7/8 that have [generic audio jacks](https://www.wpi.edu/Academics/ATC/Collaboratory/HowTo/Camtasia/Images/laptop.jpg)?